# Database is disconnected after i pass invalid login/password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have two routes:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    const newUser = new User({
      login: req.body.login,
      password: hashedPass,
      registrationDate: new Date(),
    });

    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ login: req.body.login });
    !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    !validated && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials!");

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    res.status(200).json(others);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

They both work great. But there is a problem with `login`. When i pass wrong login or wrong password the `error 400` occurs and the `Wrong credentials` is being returned. But after this, the database immediately disconnects witch an error:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\0aPSW PROJEKT\projekt-psw\Projekt-Instagram\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\0aPSW PROJEKT\projekt-psw\Projekt-Instagram\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\0aPSW PROJEKT\projekt-psw\Projekt-Instagram\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at D:\0aPSW PROJEKT\projekt-psw\Projekt-Instagram\backend\routes\users.js:54:21 {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Does anyone know, what can I do so that the database would not disconnected?

Comment: That looks like something is trying to set a header after something else has sent.  Try adding a console.log to each line in the login route so you can see which lines are being executed before the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this code to this:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ login: req.body.login });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] });
    }

    const validated = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validated) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] });
    }

    const { password, ...others } = user._doc;
    return res.status(200).send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send(error);
  }
});
```

and now everything works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).